# Java on OS X: Runtime.exec minecraft.jar doing nothing

Tags: java, macos, terminal, minecraft

I am writing a program that, as a side feature, launches Minecraft. Currently, the following runs fine on Windows:

```
String osSeparator = ";";
String osSeparatorLast = ";";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xms" + settings.MinimumMemory() + " -Xmx" + settings.MaximumMemory() + " -cp \"" + bP + "minecraft.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "jinput.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl_util.jar" + osSeparatorLast + "\" -Djava.library.path=\"" + bP + "natives\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" + " " + username + " " + sessionID);
```

Through testing, I've found the result of the following works when entered in manually to the OS X terminal:

```
String osSeparator = ":";
String osSeparatorLast = "";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java", "-Xms" + settings.MinimumMemory(), "-Xmx" + settings.MaximumMemory(), "-cp \"" + bP + "minecraft.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "jinput.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl_util.jar" + osSeparatorLast + "\"", "-Djava.library.path=\"" + bP + "natives\"", "net.minecraft.client.Minecraft", username, sessionID});
```

For some reason, the above code does not start Minecraft, but taking the string result and literally copy/pasting back into the terminal will.

What's up with this?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` returns a `Process` object.  Try reading from its input stream or error stream to see if it is reporting an error.

Comment: How do i best get this to the terminal?

Comment: One way is to use the StreamGobbler class defined here: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4

Comment: Somehow not helpful. I just need to find out why I can directly copy/paste the text result of the code and it easily starts Minecraft. It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Why is that not helpful?  If there's a problem starting Java for whatever reason, this reason will almost certainly be written to the standard error or standard output of the process.  (Admittedly I've never used Mac OS X before; I'm assuming that if it fails to start a process for some reason it will at least provide some indication of why.)

Comment: Incidentally, try splitting the `-cp` argument and its value into separate strings in the array you're passing to `exec()`, and remove the unnecessary `\"` values from each end of the value of `-cp`.  By passing an array of strings to `exec()`, Java itself will do any necessary quoting to ensure that each string element of the array ends up as a single argument to the command line.

Comment: Luke, I understand that, but the link doesn't directly explain how to access that output stream. It provides a StreamGobbler class, but no real explanation on how o use it. I just need a simple way to parse from the stream to console strings.

Comment: And splitting the args into an array won't let it work on Windows. I'll have to test it out on the mac later. I'ts not mine, so I have to wait for the user to be on.

Comment: There's an example of how to use the StreamGobbler in "Listing 4.5 GoodWindowsExec.java".  I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what's so difficult to understand about this.

Comment: Apologies. I was in a bit of a hurry and wasn't able to dig into the article. Regardless, I can't do anything until my friend comes back online. I'll try it though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're passing an array? Why is it not formatted like the 1st example?

This should work:

```
String osSeparator = ":";
String osSeparatorLast = "";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xms" + settings.MinimumMemory() + " -Xmx" + settings.MaximumMemory() + "-cp \"" + bP + "minecraft.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "jinput.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl.jar" + osSeparator + bP + "lwjgl_util.jar" + osSeparatorLast + "\"" + " -Djava.library.path=\"" + bP + "natives\" " + "net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" + username + sessionID);
```

Comment: It was like that because I read something about OSX's command parser not liking quotes and that using an array would fix that. Running as a single string doesn't work either.